# Plugin can not be seen by rcp application

Tags: eclipse, plugins, rcp

i habe a plugin written in Eclipse which used to work on a given rcp application just by adding the .jar file to the "plugin"-folder of my rcp application. Now i have a new machine (win7 64bits, JRE 1.6) and tried to export a new .jar after making minor changes to the project. Now my rcp application can not "see" my plugin any more. The old machine used to have JRE 1.5 amd was 32bits. I would appreciate it if somebody could give me a hint. I have been trying to solve this issue for 5 days without much success. Thank you very much!
Probobly the problem is with the lunch configuration or with the JRE!

Comment: Any messages in the Error view?

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to update your eclipse with deltapack to support 64bit/32bit Platform related jars.

Example:

http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.7.2-201202080800/#DeltaPack

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. It is very valuable. The problem was that some dependencies were missing. I added them again and now it works!